# How can i access and create a nested object with v-model on vue?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs and I have a problem with v-model, I want to know if has some way to access a nested object and auto-create with v-model

my html:

```html
<div class="table-values" v-for="month in months">
       <div class="month" v-text="month"></div>
       <div>      
          <input type="text" class="form-control" inputmode="decimal" @blur="test" v-model="consumption[month].rush_hour">
       </div>
       <div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" inputmode="decimal"  v-model="consumption[month].normal_hour">
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" inputmode="decimal" readonly>
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" inputmode="decimal" v-model="energy[month].rush_hour">
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" inputmode="decimal" v-model="energy[month].normal_hour">
       </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
            return {
                months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                consumption: {},
                energy: {},
            }
    })
```

I want to create this for example:

```json
{
consumption: {
  Janeiro: {
   rush_hour: 1,
   normal_hour: 2
  },
  Fevereiro: {
   rush_hour: 1,
   normal_hour: 2
  }
},
energy: {
  Janeiro: {
   rush_hour: 1,
   normal_hour: 2
  },
  Fevereiro: {
   rush_hour: 1,
   normal_hour: 2
  }
}
```

I Tested only with `v-model="Consumption[month]"` and worked, but when i use `v-model="Consumption[month]['rush_hour']"` or `v-model="Consumption[month].rush_hour"` v-model (Ex: Consumption.Janeiro.rush_hour) throw an error on console.

Answer (score 0):

If you component is increasing in complexity to come to a point like this, you better extract the logic to another component and receive the dynamic values as props so that you have something like:

```js
props: {
  month // "January"
},

data() {
  return {
    consumption: {
      rush_hour: 0,
      normal_hour: 0
    },

    energy: {
      rush_hour: 0,
      normal_hour: 0
    }
  }
}


// Somewhere, you do this:
$emit('input', {
  consumption: this.consumption,
  energy: this.energy,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because when access model of `null` (`consumption['Janeiro'] = null`)

I recommend you init your `consumption` and `energy` in your `data` function.

Here is my code:

```
data() {
const months = [
  "Janeiro",
  "Fevereiro",
  "Março",
  "Abril",
  "Maio",
  "Junho",
  "Julho",
  "Agosto",
  "Setembro",
  "Outubro",
  "Novembro",
  "Dezembro",
];

const consumption = {};
const energy = {};

const initialValue = {
  rush_hour: 1,
  normal_hour: 2,
};

months.forEach((month) => {
  consumption[month] = { ...initialValue };
  energy[month] = { ...initialValue };
});

return {
  months: months,
  consumption: consumption,
  energy: energy,
}
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-grass-oy6drc?file=/src/App.vue:1078-1656) is code sandbox.
Hope this help!